# element on other element and fixed to bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to have `div` with image and on this second div with name of the image.

If I type long lorem ipsum in `p` element, parent div is making bigger but I want to hold size of parent div and just make bigger `p` element with name.

How to do this?

I want something like the following:

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="item-slot">
    <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/something_here">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item-slot {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:rgba(20, 25, 9, 0.5);
border:1px solid #364500;
padding-top:5px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:4px;
text-align:center;
}
.item-slot>p {
background-color:red;
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
z-index:100000;
}
.item-slot>img {
top:20px;
width:85px;
height:66px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So like this? https://jsfiddle.net/2xqrqmfz/

I added relative positioning to the .item-slot, and absolute positioning to the p tag. Might want to swap the p tag out for something more appropriate since it's not a paragraph. I would probably use another div.

```css
.item-slot {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:rgba(20, 25, 9, 0.5);
border:1px solid #364500;
padding-top:5px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:4px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}
.item-slot>p {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
background-color:red;
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
z-index:100000;
}
.item-slot>img {
top:20px;
width:85px;
height:66px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-slot">
    <img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsRVx4MwFo5_T3eAQ3i6DMIW0X7ojiwoHax6egMOKGxj4G68Nz3-jCp4itjFWx-ktqfSmtcwqVx6sT/360fx360f">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Edit, added some notes.

Comment: It works very well after add `width:100%;` to `.item-slot>p` but if I want to make the same `p` element with for example class `top` the same code will work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the paragraph to expand on hovering and keep it within the div for this you can use `overflow:hidden;` in the `.item-slot` class and then on hover effect of p you can decrease top margin.

Here is the code:

```css
.item-slot {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:rgba(20, 25, 9, 0.5);
border:1px solid #364500;
padding-top:5px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:4px;
text-align:center;
overflow: hidden;
}
.item-slot>p {
background-color:red;
text-align:center;
font-size:10px;
z-index:100000;
}
.item-slot>img {
top:20px;
width:85px;
height:66px;
}
.item-slot p:hover{
  margin: -1em 0 0 0;

  
}
```

```html
<div class="item-slot">
    <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/something_here">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```